# How to retrieve input from a function

Tags: c#, function, pointers

I have the next code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Maman15cs
{
    public class ClassRoom
    {
        public string ClassNumber;
        public int NumberofPlaces;
        public int[,] DayandHour = new int[6,8];

        public void AddClassRoom()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Class number, the Number of places\n");
            ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            NumberofPlaces = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Good, now enter the Day(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and after that you put the courses' number that are that day (In Order)");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {

                    DayandHour[i,j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public class Course
    {
        public string CourseName;
        public int CourseNumber;
        public int StudentsNumber;
        public string TeacherName;
        public string ClassNumber;

        // Tuple<string, int, int, string, string>

        public void AddCourse(Course *course)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Course's name, course's number, students number, teacher's name, and class' number\n");
            CourseName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            CourseNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            StudentsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            TeacherName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

         void Main()
        {
            Course[] course = new Course[1000];
            ClassRoom[] classroom = new ClassRoom[1000];
            Course* coursePointer;


            int actionChoice;
            int courseCount = 0, classroomCount = 0;

             loop:

             Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do? (Enter number): \n  1) Add a new Course \n 2)Add a new class room \n 3)Add an existing class to an existing classroom \n 4)Read the information of a specific classroom \n 5)Read the information of all the classrooms \n 6)Read the information of a specific course \n 7)Delete a specific course \n 8)Update courses in the Time Table \n 9)Exit the program  \n");
             actionChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

             switch (actionChoice)
             {

                 case 1: //Add a new Course

                    // course[classroomCount].AddCourse();

                   break;


             }

             goto loop;

        }
    }
}
```

And I want the AddCourse function to return or use the pointer to add the input to the variable course, I tried some things like list<> but I'm not that experienced with this.

Comment: Classes in C# are passed by reference, so you don't need to explicitly use pointers. Just pass an instantiated class directly into your function and it should do what you need.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please I didn't understand your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `AddCourse` to create a new `Course` and return it.

```
public Course AddCourse()
{
     var course = new Course();
     course.CourseName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
     // ... more readlines
     return course;
 }
```

In Main:

```
List<Course> courses = new List<Course>();

case 1: courses.Add(AddCourse()); break;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set up a list to hold all your courses, and not necessarily an array (unless you really need an array):

```
List<Course> Courses = new List<Courses>();
```

Change your AddCourse method return a newly instantiated Course object:

```
Public Course AddCourse(){

Course newCourse = new Course();
<logic to populate the object>

return newCourse;

}
```

Inside your loop where you're adding courses, just do something similar to this:

```
Courses.add(AddCourse());
```

Then you can use whatever looping structure to go through all the courses or linq to get a specific one you need.

---EDIT--

Since you're stuck with the way your Course class is set up (which is not best practice btw), you will need to change the AddCourse method to something like this:

```
 public class Course
    {
        public string CourseName;
        public int CourseNumber;
        public int StudentsNumber;
        public string TeacherName;
        public string ClassNumber;
        public void AddCourse()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Course's name, course's number, students number, teacher's name, and class' number\n");
            this.CourseName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            this.CourseNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            this.StudentsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            this.TeacherName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
            this.ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        }
    }
```

Then the call in your looping method will need to be like this:

```
Course NewCourse = new Course();
Courses.Add(NewCourse.AddCourse());
```

Comment: It says me that AddCourse does not exist in the current context

Comment: Move the AddCourse method to inside the same Program Class. Either that, or move it to inside it's own class, and instantiate that class first.

Comment: How were you able to call that method in your initial code sample? You would have received the same error.

Comment: Also, your logic to populate the Course object shouldn't really be inside the Course class itself. It really belongs with the main input logic of your program, or a separate class that handles it.

Comment: I weren't that's why I asked for help

Comment: Luckily it's not me who makes the rules.

Comment: ugg, that's not really a good architecture. See my updated answer for a way to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems after switch to C# from C :)

First, you can replace `Course[] course = new Course[1000];` with `var course = new List<Course>();`. `List<T>` is much better for the most scenaros - it has no exact size, you can add any numer of elements 'on the fly', on any position.

Second, all class instances passed as reference. Pointers are usable only in some rare scenarous.

Third. `goto` almost never used in C# too. There are tons of loops, enumerators etc in the language - foreach, while, for

Last. In your case I would do it in this way:

```
public class Course
{
    public string CourseName;
    public int CourseNumber;
    public int StudentsNumber;
    public string TeacherName;
    public string ClassNumber;

    public static Course ReadCourse()
    {
        var rez = new Course();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Course's name, course's number, students number, teacher's name, and class' number\n");
        rez.CourseName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        rez.CourseNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        rez.StudentsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        rez.TeacherName = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        rez.ClassNumber = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        return rez;
    }
}

public class Program
{   
    void Main()
    {
        var courses = new List<Course>();

        int actionChoice;
        while(1=1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do? (Enter number): \n  1) Add a new Course \n 2)Add a new class room \n 3)Add an existing class to an existing classroom \n 4)Read the information of a specific classroom \n 5)Read the information of all the classrooms \n 6)Read the information of a specific course \n 7)Delete a specific course \n 8)Update courses in the Time Table \n 9)Exit the program  \n");
            actionChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (actionChoice)
            {

                case 1: //Add a new Course
                    var new_course = Course.ReadCourse();
                    courses.Add(new_course);    
                    break;

                case 9: // Exit
                    return;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is interesting here. Static method `Course.ReadCourse` which reads and return new instance of Course. `default` selector in `switch`. `return` to exit the app. `List<T>` as a storage for courses. `new Course()` command uses implicit constructor created automatically because no any constructors were defined.

Comment: I gotta thank you all guys, but especially you, you know what I am going for :)